# How can I decide network speed of my dedicated server?

Tags: bandwidth

I have a dedicated server managed by WHM which has 100 websites. Bandwidth is 1 Gbps.

I found another company which offers better CPU and RAM and HDD same price but bandwidth is 0.5 Gbps.

I am not good at calculating bandwidth that needed. What should I do?

Comment: We can't tell. Estimate, pick one, measure performance, adjust as necessary. See also:  [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider about these :

1. If you have any SLA with web sites admin about BW. It is the most important fact in your scenario.
2. Use a BW monitor software(eg cacti) to monitor your BW in a period of time to find your baseline and burst usage.this period must contain dates that your costumers's sites visit and usage will change according to their services.